# Reset an object import in a beforeEach

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I want to remember the technical explanation of this behavior and how to do it properly

**sample.js** (in reality this is a really long mock which is why its in a separate file)

```
const data = {
  a = 1,
  nested: {
     object: 'old'
  }
}

export default data;
```

**data.spec.js**

```
import sampleData from './sample'

describe('sample', () => {
let data;
 beforeEach(
  data = sampleData
 )
  it('change data', () => {
    data.nested.object = 'new'; // lets say value was old before
    ....
  })
  it('change data', () => {
   console.log(data.nested.object) // i would think it would be 'old' but is still 'new'
    ....
  })
```

My brain says that its doing so because all i did was add a pointer to the object and i'm still modifying the object so the beforeEach doesn't do anything. I feel like there's a longer explanation that I'm forgetting

But I want to know the proper way to do it. if I turn the sample data file to a function and have it 'return' the object each time That seems right given I use an arrow function. But that feels incorrect. Is there something I'm forgetting?

Comment: Don't update sampleData in place, make a copy and work with _that_ instead? Better yet, rewrite ./sample so that instead of importing `sampleData` you import `getSampleData` and have to run `const sampleData  = getSampleData()`, giving you a fresh copy each time. Right now you get an object, call it `data`, and then you modify it.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is correct, just don't forget to make a copy of your test data before changing it.

For example:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  data = structuredClone(sampleData);
});
```

Or for older ecmascript version:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  data = { ...sampleData, nested: { ...sampleData.nested } };
});
```